# How to split a string with multiple delimiters in LookML?

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, looker

I have a dataset that has values like this:

| row | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AG123E YHUKLO |
| 2 | AG654 SUHEKI |
| 3 | AG123_YHUKLO |
| 4 | AG654_SUHEKI |
| 5 | AG452D ESTWIO |

I want to extract the starting part of the string, before the space or before the _

so in LookML, I wrote:
`sql: split(regexp_extract(${column},'^AG.*'),' ')[safe_offset(0)]` This worked, but it's only extracting if the delimiter is space.

How do I also extract the value if the delimiter is _ AND space?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
^(AG[^ _]*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K0eGXv/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(AG[^ _]*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `AG` - a literal text
  - `[^ _]*` - zero or more chars other than a space and underscore.